# How to close the Terminal app using the terminal command-line("exit") in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina

I want to close the Terminal using the terminal command-line.

But when I enter the `exit` command, Terminal only logs out the session but does not close the app window. Is there any way to also close the app.

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

[image]

Comment: The title ask how to close the APP while the body ask how to close only the window. It should be clarified (the solution in the accepted answer doesn't close the app, while a solution given in another answer do close the app).

Comment: thank for the reply , now I had changed it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In **Terminal** > **Preferences…** > **Profiles** > **Shell**, the default setting for **When the shell exits:** is: **Don't close the window**

This can be changed to: **Close the window**

Then the `exit` *command* will close the *window*.

[image]

---

Edit to address the edited Question:

If you want to close the *window* using the `exit` *command* you can do as suggested in the first part of this answer, however, if you also want to automatically and gracefully close **Terminal** as well, as part of your *script* or in place of the `exit` *command* as shown in your question, then you can do the following:

First create a simple **AppleScript** *application* using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor**:

```
tell application "Terminal" to if (busy of windows) does not contain true then quit
```

Saving it as an *application* named e.g. **QuitTerminal** in the main **Applications** *folder*.

After saving it, open **Terminal** and then open e.g. **QuitTerminal** in order to trigger allowing permissions under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**

Once this is done you can then use the following at the end of your *script* or in place of the `exit` *command*:

```
open -a "OuitTerminal"
```

Example based on *command* shown in your question:

```
/Users/harikrishna/Desktop/youtube.sh ; open -a "OuitTerminal"
```

This will only close **Terminal** if there are no running processes in any of the *windows* in **Terminal**.

Note: If you do not want to see e.g. **OuitTerminal** show in the **Dock**, you can modify the *application* using the following *command* in **Terminal**:

```
defaults write '/Applications/OuitTerminal.app/Contents/Info.plist' LSUIElement -bool yes
```

---

If you do not care about any running process you can force close **Terminal** from the *script* or *command* using `killall Terminal` in place of `exit`; however this is messy and I do not recommend using it over what's presented  above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , it also worked.But I faced a difficulty while writing apple script and later I did it .But I don't understand  as the previous answer also close the window . Could you pls tell what happens or what is the difference between the exit and the QuitTerminal script you have shared here.

Comment: @Hari krishna Goli, If all you are trying to do is close the _window_ and not also **Terminal** then just use my original answer, which is what I assumed you were trying to do. If you also want to close the **Terminal** _app_ and not just one of its _windows_ then you'll need to use what I added after you edited your original question. In the first part of my answer making the change in the _preferences_ allows the `exit` _command_ to close the _window_ it's executed in, but not the _application_. My updated answer provides a way to gracefully close the _application_, not just a _window_.

Comment: @Hari krishna Goli, The reason for the **AppleScript** _application_ is to only close **Terminal** if no processes are running in any of its _windows_.